# How does this code use promises to sequentially fetch urls and load it sequentially to html?

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I am new to javascript promises, I read a tutorial on promises at [JavaScript Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-async/%22JavaScript%20Promises%22).The given code appears under the heading "Creating a sequence".

Basically story is a JSON object which has chapterUrls array containing links to various chapter JSON objects.getJSON(url) makes a GET request and on success returns a promise with a JSON object as it's promiseValue.

story json:

```
{
  "heading": "<h1>A story about something</h1>",
  "chapterUrls": [
    "chapter-1.json",
    "chapter-2.json",
    "chapter-3.json",
    "chapter-4.json",
    "chapter-5.json"
  ]
}
```

chapter Json:

```
{
  "chapter": 1,
  "html": "<p>Chapter 1 text: Cras sollicitudin orci ac velit adipiscing, ut faucibus urna auctor. Pellentesque in sem nec sem molestie malesuada. Sed aliquam mi sit amet sollicitudin luctus. Aenean quis tempus sem, in viverra metus. Maecenas sed urna bibendum, cursus lectus sed, ultricies risus.</p>"
}
```

I am not able to understand what's happening in this piece of code.How does this code **sequentially fetch chapters** and **load them to html sequentially**?

```
    // Start off with a promise that always resolves
var sequence = Promise.resolve();

// Loop through our chapter urls
story.chapterUrls.forEach(function(chapterUrl) {
  // Add these actions to the end of the sequence
  sequence = sequence.then(function() {
    return getJSON(chapterUrl);
  }).then(function(chapter) {
    addHtmlToPage(chapter.html);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forEach` loop effectively builds a then chain like this :

```
Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    return getJSON(story.chapterUrls[0]).then(function(chapter) {
        addHtmlToPage(chapter.html);
    });
}).then(function() {
    return getJSON(story.chapterUrls[1]).then(function(chapter) {
        addHtmlToPage(chapter.html);
    });
}).then(function() {
    return getJSON(story.chapterUrls[2]).then(function(chapter) {
        addHtmlToPage(chapter.html);
    });
}).then(function() {
    // etc.
});
```

Of course, there will be more or less stages depending on the length of `story.chapterUrls`.

With `Promise.resolve()` as the "seed promise", the chain will start to settle as soon as the building phase is complete (actually in as soon as possible in a later event turn). The first `getJSON()` will be called and when it resolves, the first `addHtmlToPage()` and when it resolves, the second `getJSON()` and so on (each stage in its own event turn).

Once built, the chain will resolve all the way through unless an error occurs. An error handler should be included to log/display an error, otherwise it will be silent.

```
story.chapterUrls.forEach(function(chapterUrl) {
  sequence = sequence.then(function() {
    return getJSON(chapterUrl);
  }).then(function(chapter) {
    addHtmlToPage(chapter.html);
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a limited understanding of Promises myself, but here's how I read it:

As per the comment in the code, start off with an empty `Promise` object. This promise will resolve immediately.

Then, for each chapter URL, the sequence is continued with first a `getJSON` (which itself is a promise, it will resolve when the JSON has been fetched), and then a function to add the processed JSON as HTML to the page - since this one doesn't return anything, it resolves immediately.

The idea being, since you're adding the `getJSON` and `addHtmlToPage` functions to the sequence, they will then be resolved in order. The main factor is the `getJSON` one itself being a promise, which resolves only when the request is complete. In this way, it will load them one by one, in the order of the array.

This would be in contrast to more "traditional" AJAX requests, where they may not complete in the same order they were sent. Before Promises were really a "thing", the AJAX request would have to be made synchronous, or otherwise clever trickery would have to be done (for instance, putting an empty `<div>` to serve as a placeholder, which the AJAX request will fill when complete).

Comment: So on the first run sequence is already resolved hence it executes .then() to fetch first url. However on the second run, .then() will be executed only if the previous fetch was successful as sequence was assigned to the result of previous call. So basically looping through this statement am doing something like this: `sequence.then(function() {
    return getJSON(chapterUrl[0]);
  }).then(function(chapter) {
    addHtmlToPage(chapter.html);
  }).then(function() {
    return getJSON(chapterUrl[1]);
  }).then(function(chapter) {
    addHtmlToPage(chapter.html);//so on`  Am I right?